# Mule ESB access to Service

Tags: mule, esb

Is there a way for me to access a Mule service, programmatically, similar to the way we get access to a Spring bean via Spring container?

Something like

```
Service s = .....getService("Service1");

<model>
  <service name="Service1">
    <inbound>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
Service service1 = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupService("Service1");
```